# Trouble installing SQL Server 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008

Greetings,

As a developer I want to have SQL Server 2008 installed on my laptop. However when trying to install the management tools (basic and complete) it keeps whining about 
`Another version Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 has been detected on this system that must be updated to SP1. Please update all Visual Studio 2008 installations to SP1 level, by visitiing Microsoft Update`

However when looking my in programs in control panel there is no such thing installed as visual studio 2008.

Visual studio 2010 is installed however is at version: "10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel".. this makes me assume SP1 is installed for Visual Studio 2010.

I have tried full re-install of SQL Server.

I have run CCleaner and it has remove a lot of keys on Visual Studio 2008 but the problem still remains.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem or what I can still try?

Comment: SuperUser or ServerVault will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Sql Server 2008 also installs SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio.  This might be the program it's talking about.  I'm assuming you tried using Microsoft Update to try and resolve the problem, right?

Was there ever VS 2008 on your laptop?  I recently wiped my laptop clean and installed VS2010 and then Sql Server 2008 and didn't run into this issue.  I did do all the Microsoft Updates available after installing VS2010 and again after installing Sql Server 2008.

Comment: as far as I know, visual studio 2008 has never been installed but I did find traces of it on my hard drive aswell as in the registry. Removed them all but still the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Just run Microsoft update, if any SP would be available it will be updated

Comment: I have installed every possible update given by windows update

Comment: If this is a corporate environment, WSUS may be involved and Service Pack's might not be approved, so wouldn't show in Windows Update. I know whenever a new Service Pack comes through on my WSUS server, it is always unapproved for several months while we evaluate what it's going to break and what's changed.